# zend form with 2(two) Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists, only one works

Tags: zend-framework

Hello i have a Zend Form with 2(two) Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists toghether like this :

```
    $ditta_esiste = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(
            array(
                'table' => 'ditta',
                'field' => 'id'
            )
    );

    $this->getElement('ditta')->setAttrib('id', 'nome_ditta')->setRequired(true);
    $this->getElement('ditta_id')->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty(), false)->addValidator($ditta_esiste, false);


    $marca_esiste = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(// ZEND IMBECILLE NON FUNZIONA QUESTO CONTROLLO
        'marca', 'id'
    );

    $this->getElement('marca_id')->addValidator($marca_esiste, false);
```

the second validator never triggers, i can put garbage in it's constructor and it woun't care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend framework doesn't allow two validators of the same class to be used on the same element... [See This Bug Report (Read Comments Too)](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6904)

A work around is to create your own validator class that extends Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists and then use that as your second validator.

Comment: but those are two different text elements, one is ditta_id and another one is marca_id